# Condition for integrability on finite measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable real function, show that, $f\in L^1(\mu)$ iff $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(\{f\geq n\})<\infty$. Am a bit stuck on the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction so any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please replace $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu[\{f\geq n\}]\leq\infty$ by $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu[\{|f|\geq n\}]\lt\infty$ (two modifications).

Comment: I see why you want to replace it, but the question which I was told is completely correct was to show $f\in L^1$ iff $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(\{f\geq n\})<\infty$. So for the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction the inequality: $|f|\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1_{|f|\geq n}$ will not work, unless $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(\{f\geq n\})<\infty\Rightarrow\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(\{|f|\geq n\})<\infty$, which I doubt is true. So any ideas how to proceed. Thanks again.

Comment: I love the faith displayed by your "the question which I was told is completely correct". For the mathematical reasons why the implication you are trying to prove cannot hold, see the comment to my answer. By the way: what is your source?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the sets $A_n=\{|f|\geqslant n\}$ and integrate the double inequality
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{A_n}\leqslant |f|\leqslant\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{A_n}.
$$
Thus, $f$ is integrable if and only if
the series $\sum\limits_n\mu(A_n)$ converges.

The hypothesis that $\mu$ is finite is there to ensure that the $n=0$ term $\mu(A_0)=\mu(X)$ is finite.

The double inequality above stems from the pointwise relations, valid for every nonnegative $t$,
$$
\lfloor t\rfloor=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{t\geqslant n}\leqslant t\lt1+\lfloor t\rfloor=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{t\geqslant n}.
$$

Comment: Sorry don't see all of it yet so can you explain how you got the above inequality, as f can be negative? Also are you using the dominated convergence theorem to interchange infinite sum and integration? Thanks

Comment: Ok is the sign of f not really important as we should just deal with $|f|$? Think I see it now so just use $|f|$.  Any the interchange of sum of integral is correct because of the dominated convergence Theorem? Thanks again

Comment: Think I see the 1st inequlity now so just use $|f|$, but dont quite see the 2nd inequality(i.e $|f|\leq\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}1_{A_n}$, can you explain why it is true?

Comment: I thought you assumed $f$ to be nonnegative, sorry for this oversight. The interchange of sum and integral is valid because everything is nonnegative. About the inequalities, see Edit.

Comment: Thanks again but do we really need $\mu$ to be a finte measure. Certainly if $f$ is an arbitrary measurable function then it won't really be the case that $X=A_0$. We certainly don't need it $\Rightarrow$ direction; and for the converse as you pointed out $|f|\leq\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}1_{A_n}$, so integrating on both side would give $\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty$, i.e. $f\in L^1$.  Am I right, please can you let me know if I am and if I am wrong please point out where my mistake is. Thanks

Comment: Note that $A_0=X$ **always** hence the integral of the RHS is never finite when $\mu$ is not finite.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see why $X=A_0$ if $f$ is not nonegative? When $\mu(f<0)>0$ we still have $f(x)\leq\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}1_{A_n}(x)$ $\forall x\in X$ as if $f(x)<0$ the sum is $0$, then as the sum converges this forces the integral to be finite. For the converse when $f\in L^1$ the inequality $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{A_n}\leq |f|$ will then imply $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)<\infty$, so we would need to also have $\mu(A_0)<\infty$ to get $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)<\infty$ but not that $\mu$ is finite. Let me know if this is right and if not please correct me.

Comment: Because $A_0=\{|f|\geqslant0\}$. The condition in the current version of your post (using $f$ instead of $|f|$) is absurd, see my comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ok, I see that as $f$ is not nonngetative and not assumed to be in $L^1$, we can't use the monotone property of the integral, and I see why you changed the $A_n$'s but then this doesn't answer the question. The assumption was that just the it is a finite measure space and $f$ is measurable. So for the $\Leftarrow$ direction we can't use the inequality. So how can we show  $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(\{f\geq n\})<\infty\Rightarrow f\in L^1$? Thanks again really appreciate your input.

Comment: Once again: the implication at the end of your last comment DOES NOT HOLD, for obvious reasons, unless one assumes that $f$ is almost surely nonnegative. Note that the convergence of the series you wrote tells you NOTHING about the behaviour of the negative part of $f$ hence it DOES NOT imply that $f$ is integrable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lovely application of [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma): by assumption, $\Sigma_n \mu(|f| \geq n) < \infty$, hence the aforementioned lemma tells us $\limsup_n \{|f| \geq n\}$ is a null set.

In other words
$$
\mu(\forall n \in \mathbb N\,\exists m \geq n\; |f| \geq m) = 0
$$
which is a convoluted way to say that $f$ is essentially bounded. Therefore
$$
\int |f| \,d\mu \leq M\,\mu(X)
$$
for some finite constant $M \geq 0$, and $f$ is integrable.

Answer (score -1):

In general, the $\Leftarrow$ direction does not hold because if we
can find $g\geq1$ with $\int g=\infty$. Put $f=-g$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu([f\geq n])=0$
but $f$ is not integrable.

To avoid typing the sign of absolute value, I modify $f$ to ''$f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$''.

For each $n=0,1,2,\ldots,$let $A_{n}=\{x\mid f(x)\in[n,n+1)\}$.
Let $B_{n}=[f\geq n]$. Observe that $A_{n}=B_{n}\setminus B_{n+1}$,
so $\mu(A_{n})=\mu(B_{n})-\mu(B_{n+1})$. Also, $A_{0},A_{1},\ldots$
are pairwisely disjoint with $\cup_{n}A_{n}=X$.

Suppose that $\int f<\infty$. By Monotone Convergence Theorem, $$\int f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{A_{n}}f\geq\sum_{n}n\mu(A_{n})=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N}n\left(\mu(B_{n})-\mu(B_{n+1})\right)\geq\sum_{n=0}^{N}n\left(\mu(B_{n})-\mu(B_{n+1})\right)$$
for any $N$. Observe that $\sum_{n=0}^{N}n\left(\mu(B_{n})-\mu(B_{n+1})\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu(B_{n})-N\mu(B_{N+1})$.
Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\mu(B_{n})\leq N\mu(B_{N+1})+\int f+\mu(B_{0})$.
Note that $N\mu(B_{N+1})\leq\int_{B_{N+1}}f\leq\int f.$ Hence, $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\mu(B_{n})\leq2\int f+\mu(B_{0})$.
Letting $N\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(B_{n})\leq2\int f+\mu(B_{0})<\infty$.

Conversely, suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(B_{n})<\infty$.
Note that $\int f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{A_{n}}f\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\mu(A_{n})$.
For each $N$, $\sum_{n=0}^{N}(n+1)\mu(A_{n})=\sum_{n=0}^{N}(n+1)\left(\mu(B_{n})-\mu(B_{n+1})\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\mu(B_{n})-(N+1)\mu(B_{N+1})\leq\sum_{n=0}^{N}\mu(B_{n})$.
Letting $N\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\int f\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\mu(A_{n})\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(B_{n})<\infty$.