# Finiteness assumption on $L^1$ condition

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and $u$ be a measurable function. Show that
$$
     \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu\{\vert u \vert \ge n\} \le \int \vert u \vert d\mu \le \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu\{\vert u \vert \ge n\}
$$
In the proof, I am able to show that
$$
    \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1\{\vert u \vert \ge n \} \le \vert u \vert \le \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 1\{\vert u \vert \ge n \} \ \forall x \in X
$$
and thus, an application of Beppo Levi theorem, we achieve the inequalities.

**My question:** Why is the finiteness of the measure $\mu$ needed ? It seems to me that for an arbitrary measure space, the inequalities still holds.

Comment: This works in any measure space.

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes, I'm aware. But how is it matter ? The inequalities still holds

Comment: @whpowell96 just being pedantic with wording for OP: for the purposes of the inequality, that’s not relevant, and in fact having $\infty$ on the RHS makes the inequality all the more trivial. The finiteness assumption is usually there to deduce an equivalent condition for integrability (something which OP doesn’t mention), in which case your comment is 100% on point. OP: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/819742/568204).